# How do I check for an unmangled C++ symbol when building a PHP extension?

Tags: c++, automake, php-extension, name-mangling

I have a PHP module written in C++, which relies on a C++ library (Boost Date_Time) being installed.

Currently, in my config.m4 file I'm checking for the library as follows:

```
  LIBNAME=boost_date_time
  LIBSYMBOL=_ZN5boost9gregorian9bad_monthD0Ev

  PHP_CHECK_LIBRARY($LIBNAME,$LIBSYMBOL,,
  [
    AC_MSG_ERROR([lib $LIBNAME not found.  Try: sudo apt-get install libboost-dev])
  ],[
    -lstdc++ -ldl
  ])
```

Now, this works in my current environment, but I'm painfully aware this will probably break on a different version of the library or compiler.

How can I get automake to understand the non-mangled C++ symbol?

Edit:

I realise that checking on the mangled name is horrible, but is there not some way of checking for the symbol name as returned by "nm -C" (eg boost::gregorian::bad_month etc).

I found some refence to the automake command AC_LANG_CPLUSPLUS(), but I'm not sure how to use it and whether it's applicable here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check `AC_TRY_COMPILE` with something like that:

```
LIBNAME=boost_date_time
AC_MSG_CHECKING([for BOOST])
AC_TRY_COMPILE(
[
#include "boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp"
],
[
boost::gregorian::bad_month* bm = new boost::gregorian::bad_month;
],
[
AC_MSG_RESULT(yes)
],
[
AC_MSG_ERROR([lib $LIBNAME not found.  Try: sudo apt-get install libboost-dev])
])
```

This avoid the use of unmangled symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of the environment of a particular C++ compiler, there is no "non-mangled C++ symbol" - the mangling is done precisely to provide a unique name to external tools, such as linkers and librarians.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a set of C++ wrappers for the Boost api functions that you wish to invoke. These wrappers need to be declared with `extern "C"`, as in:

```
extern "C" 
void foo(int bar) 
{
...
}
```

Your PHP code should use these wrappers, rather than trying to directly call C++ methods.

**EDIT**: Since you're assuming the availability of `automake`, you're probably planning to compile the Boost library as part of the install. This gives you the option of probing the result of the name mangling. Try creating a test C++ program along these lines. **Note that this only needs to compile**; it doesn't need to produce a valid result.

```
#include "boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp"
int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
   boost::gregorian::bad_month* xxxjunk = new boost::gregorian::bad_month;
   return 0;
}
```

In your automake, you'd want to compile this, then run the output through

```
nm -C | grep "boost::gregorian::bad_month"
```

Depending on your needs and pickiness, you might want to further refine the `grep` command to look for the string "`typeinfo for boost::gregorian::bad_month`" (note that this further increases your dependency on the specific compiler implementation.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a terrible idea -- to have mangled symbols out in the open. Why'd you need this in the first place?

Having seen your update, I'd have to ask, why not use a custom rule to invoke `nm` and get this information and make this rule to be passed as a requirement? I would be very surprised if `autoconf` was to provide a direct command to check object files for symbols.

Comment: I can understand his motivation - the mangled name will be in the library or not, if not there it is an error. He isn't actually trying to call a mangled (or unmangled, in this context) function.

Comment: Adding a custom rule isn't a bad idea.  Note that the `PHP_CHECK_LIBRARY($LIBNAME,$LIBSYMBOL,,` etc part of the command is exactly that - a PHP specific macro to check object files for symbols.  But for C symbols only, of course.